# Rails gem for browsing a client user's file system

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm Looking for a Rails gem that will allow a user accessing a Rails-based  web application to browse to a file.

I will then use code to read the document's content into memory and run that through an analysis service. I do not need to persist the document onto the server; just browse to it like you would with any file system browser/manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not going to be a ruby gem that will enable you to browse a client's file system.  This would be a serious security issue if servers could navigate through client systems.

The closest thing you'll find is the html input type of file, which you'll recognize as from websites that allow users to upload files.  But even this will only provide the server with the contents of the uploaded file, not details of where on a user's computer it came from.  Drag and drop uploads work in the same way (with a little javascript).

See the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_select